# How to make the downlaodaed ros package under /opt/ros/kinetic/share?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I am currently trying to read the Sick s300 raw data for my navigation project. I created workspace using

```
catkin_make
```

and my problem is when I am inside the workspace and call

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

I can have my package in the respective workspace path.
But I need to make the package under

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

Can anyone help me with making the downloaded package under /opt/ros/kinetic/share
your assistance is always appreciatable.
thamk u!

---

Edit: @gvdhoorn Thanq sir for ur valuable time!!

I received the error of

```
-kinetic-cob-sick-s300 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-lunar-navigation-experimental : Depends: ros-lunar-assisted-teleop but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried apt-get -f install

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

I am very new to ROS. Please help me in clearing this error.
Thanq sir!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323995/how-to-make-the-downlaodaed-ros-package-under-/opt/ros/kinetic/share?/) by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-25**:\

> But I need to make the package under `/opt/ros/kinetic/share`

why?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-05-25**:
Is this related to this question #q323846?

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-05-25**:
@gvdhoorn
because I cant run my launch file and I am getting the error of cannot launch node.

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-05-25**:
@jayess S sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> because I cant run my launch file and I am getting the error of cannot launch node.

From #q323846 it seems you are trying to use `cob_sick_s300`. Is that correct?

If so: do you really need to build that package from source? It's been released into Kinetic, so a simple `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ros-kinetic-cob-sick-s300` should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-05-26**:
If you're installing via `apt`, you need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo apt install <package>
```

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-05-27**:
I also used **sudo**  too

**Comment by [KrishKannan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/41611/krishkannan_007/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thank u so much sir! @gvdhoorn and @jayess
It is added now in /opt/ros/kinetic/share